# for loop in simple java car game

Tags: java, for-loop

This is an assignment, so much of the structure is prescribed. We have a package with two classes, one `Car` and one `City`. In the `main` method of *City*, the `cars` have been set up to run into each other at 9,0. We have to code so that the program will detect when the car crashes. I'm looking at the nested for loop in *City* and can't quite figure out how to make it work.

Car class:

```
public class Car {
    private int x ,y;
    private int facing; 
    /*
     * where 0 = north, 1 = east, 2 = south, 3 = west.
     */
    private int distance; 

    public Car(int x, int y, int facing){
        //"this" only has to be used because 
        //the variable names are identical
        //"this" indicates that the variable
        //declared at the top is being referenced.
        //the x on the right-hand side is the local
        //variable in the method
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.facing = facing;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getFacing() {
        return facing;
    }

    public void setFacing(int facing) {
        this.facing = facing;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public void turnLeft() {
        if (facing == 0) {
            facing = 3;
        }
        else {
            facing -= 1;
        }
    }

    public void turnRight() {
        if (facing == 3) {
            facing = 0;
        }
        else {
            facing += 1;
        }
    }

    public void move (int distance) {
        if (facing == 0) {
            distance = distance + y; 
            y = distance;
        }
        else if (facing == 1) {
            distance = distance + x;
            x = distance;
        }
        else if (facing == 2) {
            distance = y - distance;
            y = distance;
        }
        else {
            distance = x - distance;
            x = distance;
        }
    }
}
```

City class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class City {
    private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;

    public City (int sizeX, int sizeY) {
    }

public void addCar(Car car) {
    cars.add(car);
    }

    public void moveCar(Car car, int distance) {
        for (int n = 0; n<distance; n++) {
            car.move(1);

            for (int i = 0; i<cars.size(); i++) {
                Car otherCar = cars.get(i);
                if (car != otherCar) {
                    ////this is where I'm getting stuck
                    //trying to figure out how to use this
                    //to detect when cars run into each other
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Car is at "+ "" + car.getX() + ","+ car.getY() +"\n");
    }

    public int getSizeX() {
        return sizeX;
    }

    public void setSizeX(int sizeX) {
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
    }

    public int getSizeY() {
        return sizeY;
    }

    public void setSizeY(int sizeY) {
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        City city = new City(10,10);
        Car c1 = new Car(0,0,1);
        Car c2 = new Car(9,9,2);
        city.addCar(c1);
        city.addCar(c2);
        city.moveCar(c1,9);
        city.moveCar(c2,9);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's like the whole part of the assignment! Try it yourself first

Comment: search how to compare objects equality in java

Comment: Cars run into each other when their position (X and Y) are equal.

Comment: you are also not saying on what axis you are moving the car

Comment: @hiafzhan, thank you for the tip. I'll do some research on that.

Comment: @MaxZoom, thank you. That's what I'm trying to get to, I'm just not solving it yet. I'll keep working!  @ Burdu, in this project, we're setting the axis in an elementary way -- where x,y, and facing are set in the main method by calling on Car. We're supposed to improve that with random assignments later, but we're building this in pieces. It's easier for the instructor to test our programs if everyone's output is the same at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, this is your problem:

```
if (car != otherCar)
```

The reason for this:  both `car` and `otherCar` are objects of type `Car`, so `==` will only check to see if they're the exact same instance.

The conventional thing to do is to override `equals()` in `Car`.  It seems that you're attempting to define equality when both cars are in the same coordinate location, so I'll provide that hint here.

What to do in cases of one of your parameters being `null` or not of type `Car`, or if it's the same instance (where you *would* use `==`), I leave as an exercise for the reader.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    Car otherCar = (Car) other;
    return otherCar.getX() == this.x && otherCar.getY() == this.y;
}
```

Comment: check `other` is null or not...

Comment: @haifzhan:  I *said* that's an exercise for the reader.  I know darn well what this `equals` method is missing; I simply don't want one to be capable of carte-blanche copying it into their code.

Comment: like for carte-blanche!

Comment: When you override the `equals()` you should adjust the `hashCode()` as well

Comment: @MaxZoom:  I refer you to my earlier remark - this is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, Makoto. I'm going to work on this as a practice. Unfortunately, we're told to incorporate size() into this because we're supposed to be figuring out how to manipulate List<Car>.

Comment: @JennyJ:  That has nothing to do with you checking for a collision.  But fair enough.